# How to pass Array list from android to soap Web Service?

Tags: android, arrays, sql-server, list, soap

In this code I have to insert sqlite data's to SQL server.First I have to store all data's in sqlite database and then clicking a button the entire data should be inserted in SQL server.My problem is the first row only inserted in all rows.For example; if I inserted three different rows in Sqlite,but the three rows have same first row values in Sql server.... how to resolve.

I'm using the array list in this one,I don't know how to pass those array list in soap web service..

Guys I'm in critical Position,I need your help

```
  push.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {



    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ArrayList<Details>  lst=new ArrayList<Details>();

        Database db=new Database(MainActivity.this);
        SQLiteDatabase sb=db.getReadableDatabase();

           Details det=new Details();

           Cursor cus=sb.rawQuery("select * from Auction",null);

            cus.moveToFirst();

            SoapObject request=new SoapObject(WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE,OPERATION_NAME);

            for(int i=0;i<cus.getCount();i++)
            {

         det.Boatnum= cus.getString(0).toString();

         det. Buyername=cus.getString(1).toString();
         det. amount=     cus.getString(2).toString();

        lst.add(det);  //Array list values


                request.addProperty("Boatnum",det.Boatnum);

                    request.addProperty("Buyername",det.Buyername);

                  request.addProperty("amount",det.amount);


                                envelope=new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                                envelope.dotNet=true;


                                envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);


                                httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(SOAP_ADDRESS);



                                try {

                                     serviceCall();



                                } 



                                catch (Exception exception) {



        }    
            cus.moveToNext();

            }
         }



    });
```

Comment: getString(i) not 0 1 2

Comment: if i change getstring(i),still have the same values doesn't insert next rows,please check my for loop,is that a correct one

Comment: ohhh put this in for loop Details det=new Details();

Comment: no yaar..having same issue...